# Method Parameter NSUInteger and call using IndexPath.row gives warning to use a type cast

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am surprised that the following calls result in type-cast warning:

I have a class MyClass with the following method:

```
- (id) initWithData:(NSUInteger)mNumber;
```

when I call this method using

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   MyClass *lClass = [[MyClass alloc] initWithData:indexPath.row];
   ...
```

I get a warning "Passing argument 1 of 'initWithData' makes pointer from integer without a cast".

When I typecast 'initWithData' like this:

```
MyClass *lClass = [[MyClass alloc] initWithData:(NSUInteger)indexPath.row];
```

the warning remains unchanged indicating I haven't addressed the cause of the message.
Anyone knows where and why I am getting off the track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try renaming `-initWithData:` to other names like `-initWithRowNumber:`. The compiler may be confusing it with `-[NSData initWithData:]` which takes an NSData* as input, not NSUInteger.

Comment: I agree. In particular, *alloc* 's return value is of type *id*. So it's not really type-safe.

Comment: I renamed it to initWithContent and the warning vanished ... Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Renamem initWithData to something else.